# How would I search for text that contains emojis?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, search, emoji

We have a MySQL InnoDB table, with a text field `COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. I need to search for rows that contain any emoji characters. I've searched through quite a few SO questions, but people seem to have a list of emojis they are searching for. I'm actually looking for a solution that will find ANY emoji.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35010052/searching-emoji-from-varchar-column-returns-different-record) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41147829/how-can-i-search-by-emoji-in-mysql-using-utf8mb4) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462979/searching-for-emojis-in-mysql) posts that are not helping.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546842/how-to-search-for-special-characters-unicode-characters-and-emojis-in-a-mysql) seems to come closest to actually providing me with what I'm looking for, but the OP hasn't actually posted his search code.

Thanks!

Comment: I din't tried it but ... you can import all emojis in one table from http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/5.0/ and then join through  `like` condition to your own table.

Comment: What do you want to do with the found rows?

Comment: @Stefan Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @ThomasPaine Sorry, not quite, I ended up implementing the requirement in the application layer. Best of luck in your search

Comment: you were on a good track, I posted answer although probably  a bit late. 

Answer (score 15):

I've had situation where db migration from one server to another caused emoji to disappear. So I had to find all rows in original table which contained high utf8 (emoji) characters.

This query worked as expected:

```
SELECT field FROM `table` WHERE HEX(field) RLIKE "^(..)*F.";
```

before doing anything check if you are using utf8mb4 on your db, tables AND connection:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';

+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Good, but not perfect.  For instance, it doesn't catch ✌️ which appears to HEX's as `E29C 8CEF B88F` (spaces added for clarity)

Answer (score 1):

I not bad regular expression for it. But still it can miss some emojies

```
WHERE your_column REGEXP '[\\x{1F000}-\\x{1FFFF}]';
```

Answer (score 0):

Could this work maybe ?

Use the lib_mysqludf_preg library from the mysql UDF repository for PCRE regular expressions directly in mysql

`[\x{23}\x{2A}\x{30}-\x{39}\x{A9}\x{AE}\x{203C}\x{2049}\x{2122}\x{2139}\x{2194}-\x{2199}\x{21A9}-\x{21AA}\x{231A}-\x{231B}\x{2328}\x{23CF}\x{23E9}-\x{23F3}\x{23F8}-\x{23FA}\x{24C2}\x{25AA}-\x{25AB}\x{25B6}\x{25C0}\x{25FB}-\x{25FE}\x{2600}-\x{2604}\x{260E}\x{2611}\x{2614}-\x{2615}\x{2618}\x{261D}\x{2620}\x{2622}-\x{2623}\x{2626}\x{262A}\x{262E}-\x{262F}\x{2638}-\x{263A}\x{2640}\x{2642}\x{2648}-\x{2653}\x{2660}\x{2663}\x{2665}-\x{2666}\x{2668}\x{267B}\x{267F}\x{2692}-\x{2697}\x{2699}\x{269B}-\x{269C}\x{26A0}-\x{26A1}\x{26AA}-\x{26AB}\x{26B0}-\x{26B1}\x{26BD}-\x{26BE}\x{26C4}-\x{26C5}\x{26C8}\x{26CE}-\x{26CF}\x{26D1}\x{26D3}-\x{26D4}\x{26E9}-\x{26EA}\x{26F0}-\x{26F5}\x{26F7}-\x{26FA}\x{26FD}\x{2702}\x{2705}\x{2708}-\x{270D}\x{270F}\x{2712}\x{2714}\x{2716}\x{271D}\x{2721}\x{2728}\x{2733}-\x{2734}\x{2744}\x{2747}\x{274C}\x{274E}\x{2753}-\x{2755}\x{2757}\x{2763}-\x{2764}\x{2795}-\x{2797}\x{27A1}\x{27B0}\x{27BF}\x{2934}-\x{2935}\x{2B05}-\x{2B07}\x{2B1B}-\x{2B1C}\x{2B50}\x{2B55}\x{3030}\x{303D}\x{3297}\x{3299}\x{1F004}\x{1F0CF}\x{1F170}-\x{1F171}\x{1F17E}-\x{1F17F}\x{1F18E}\x{1F191}-\x{1F19A}\x{1F1E6}-\x{1F1FF}\x{1F201}-\x{1F202}\x{1F21A}\x{1F22F}\x{1F232}-\x{1F23A}\x{1F250}-\x{1F251}\x{1F300}-\x{1F321}\x{1F324}-\x{1F393}\x{1F396}-\x{1F397}\x{1F399}-\x{1F39B}\x{1F39E}-\x{1F3F0}\x{1F3F3}-\x{1F3F5}\x{1F3F7}-\x{1F4FD}\x{1F4FF}-\x{1F53D}\x{1F549}-\x{1F54E}\x{1F550}-\x{1F567}\x{1F56F}-\x{1F570}\x{1F573}-\x{1F57A}\x{1F587}\x{1F58A}-\x{1F58D}\x{1F590}\x{1F595}-\x{1F596}\x{1F5A4}-\x{1F5A5}\x{1F5A8}\x{1F5B1}-\x{1F5B2}\x{1F5BC}\x{1F5C2}-\x{1F5C4}\x{1F5D1}-\x{1F5D3}\x{1F5DC}-\x{1F5DE}\x{1F5E1}\x{1F5E3}\x{1F5E8}\x{1F5EF}\x{1F5F3}\x{1F5FA}-\x{1F64F}\x{1F680}-\x{1F6C5}\x{1F6CB}-\x{1F6D2}\x{1F6E0}-\x{1F6E5}\x{1F6E9}\x{1F6EB}-\x{1F6EC}\x{1F6F0}\x{1F6F3}-\x{1F6F6}\x{1F910}-\x{1F91E}\x{1F920}-\x{1F927}\x{1F930}\x{1F933}-\x{1F93A}\x{1F93C}-\x{1F93E}\x{1F940}-\x{1F945}\x{1F947}-\x{1F94B}\x{1F950}-\x{1F95E}\x{1F980}-\x{1F991}\x{1F9C0}]`

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion the easy way is to create a table with all emoji codes and then make a join through `like` condition to your table.

I share here [how to insert emotis on mysql](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9636c/1/0):

```
create table emojis (
  e varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
 );

 insert into emojis values
 ( _utf8mb4 0xF09F9881 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci),
 ( _utf8mb4 '' );
```

[image]

[image]

The final query should look like:

```
select distinct yt.id
from your_table yt
inner join emojis e 
  on yt.some_column like '%' + e.e + '%'
```